# Using Windows 10 Game Bar to record SideSync

Tags: windows-10, android, screen-recorder

I am using SideSync to display my Android phones screen on my Windows 10 computer.

I am trying to record a video of my phone's screen using the Windows 10 Game Bar.

I get sound and the curser moving around but everything else is black.

[What I want to See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wulr.png)

[What I actually Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjPlU.png)

I cannot figure out what why the screen is not getting recorded in the video and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: This particular function received some updated functionality in 1903.  What version of Windows 10 are you running?

Comment: Windows 10 Home Edition. Version 1803.

Comment: Maybe try using step recorder?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think that the Game Bar screen recorder has some limited copyright protection services, which block it from recording certain windows and programs. In this instance, this feature is being triggered. The only thing I can recommend is using a different screen recorder. Sorry.

(Disclaimer: I may be totally wrong and SideSync may be using a different buffering method to display that is not what the Game Bar's Screen Recorder is looking for. The recommendation is the same though.)